# Create a batch file to download multiple url

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

downloader is `download.exe`

```
@echo off
set /p %d% `enter file to load here`
download.exe -u www.xyz.com/1s21.zip -o 1s21.zip
download.exe -u www.xyz.com/1s22.zip -o 1s22.zip
download.exe -u www.xyz.com/1d23.zip -o 1d23.zip
download.exe -u www.xyz.com/1411.zip -o 1411.zip
download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%d%.zip -o %d%.zip
....
...
..
.
```

can i use variable `%d%` that will load the name from another file so i down't have to write whole program again and agaian

and structure of `%d%` file look like this

```
1s21
1s22
1s23
...
..
.
```

---

What I want is to read a file containing names and plug those names into the download script.

Comment: I edited the snot out of this question, and still feel like I barely made a dent.  I'm giving up for the evening.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (filename) do download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%%i -o %%i
```

This will do what you want.

The normal for

```
for %%i in (item1 item2 item3)
```

reads the list from in between the brackets

The `/f` option tells it that a filename exists between the brackets and the list has to be read from the file.

for every item in the list, the part after the `do` will be called.

This assumes there is only one file name per line of the file.

Also, if you have multiple commands you need to execute for each item in the list, you can do

```
for /f %%i in (filename) do (
first command
second command
)
```

Use this example to debug your issue

```
C:\tmp>type names.txt
kd11
kd12

C:\tmp>type down.bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for /f %%i in (names.txt) do echo %%i

C:\tmp>down.bat
kd11
kd12
```

If the above works, then change the for to

```
for /f %%i in (names.txt) do download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%%i -o %%i
```

Comment: url not found please give more example

Comment: @user2276700 can you tell what was the exact `for` line you used and also the content of the file you are picking up the input from?

Comment: @user2276700 - also try this `for /f %%i in (filename) do echo download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%%i -o %%i` - this will just echo the command rather than executing it - will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: output::;;download.exe -u www.xyz.com/for -o for

Comment: Did you put the filename in (filename). What does the file contain? Please type out your for command? I think you may have typed `for /f %%i in (for) do download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%%i -o %%i`

Comment: THIS IS NAMES.TXT  for %%i in (KD11 KD22)
YES i have written (names.txt) in main program

Comment: Type out your for command here. What is KD11 KD22?

Comment: @echo off
for /f %%i in (names.txt) do echo download.exe -u www.xyz.com/%%i -o %%i
pause
it should download  www.xyz.com/KD11 and then  www.xyz.com/KD22

Comment: Can you try to add `setlocal EnableExtensions` as 2nd line - in between the echo off and the for. May be command extensions aren't enabled in your machine. I don't have any more ideas. this works fine on a couple of machines I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (names.txt) do download.exe -u "www.xyz.com/%%~i.zip" -o "%%~i.zip"
```

Comment: this does the job but when i use -o "%%i.flv"
it says failed to open file "myfilenameinnames.txt"

Comment: my names.txt have structure like this kd/10
so "/" is causing conflict as we can't save it right any alternate or can i skip / part using another name file???

Comment: You can't use Unix/Mac names in Windows, try `copy nul "my/text.txt"` and look at the error message. Rename the files in Unix/OSX before.

Comment: Overwrite names.txt? (Yes/No/All): yes
        1 file(s) copied.
but u know -o tag is output file so as said earlier names.txt has 
"/"
can i use two tags one for %%i and one for specifying the -o %%k as file names
i want that it should load names.txt for downloading zip and other file eg down.txt for output of files

Comment: OK, I dont't know the program `download.exe`, and if it needs `/` slashes. The name for the `-o` parameter is from in the names file `names.txt`.

Comment: no it doesn't need / the url have / 
can i use another file to specify output names
and thanks for helping me %%i works now and i am able to download but not able to provide the name what i want it to be saved :)

Comment: You can use an other file, if you want. In this case you should edit your question and post the structure of this file line by line.

Comment: thanks i dont need it this is what all we want :)))))